# Unable to delete data from SQLite database in iphone application

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am not able to delete data from SQlite database. I have created a database of Places.
and I am able to display it in UItableView. But when I try to delete something from it code crashes.

The error I am getting is

> Assertion failure in -[Place deleteFromDatabase], /Desktop/Current_cortes/Classes/Place.m:148
>
> Terminating app  due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error: failed to prepare statement with message 'library routine called out of sequence'.

Here is the the part where program crashed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {
        
        NSLog(@"Rows can be edited");
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        Place *PlaceObj = [appDelegate.PlacesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [appDelegate removePlace: PlaceObj];
        
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
```

The error is occurring on the line with `[appDelegate removePlace: PlaceObj];`.

The definitions of `removePlace` and `deleteFromDatabase` are as follows:

```
(void) removePlace:(Place *)PlaceObj 
{
    
    NSLog(@"remove place called");
    //Delete it from the database.
    [PlaceObj deleteFromDatabase];
    
    //Remove it from the array.
    [PlacesArray removeObject:PlaceObj];
}

-(void) deleteFromDatabase {
    if (delete_statment == nil) {
        const char *sql = "DELETE FROM places_table WHERE PlaceID=?";
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &delete_statment, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to prepare statement with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }
    
    sqlite3_bind_int(delete_statment, 1, PlaceID);
    int success = sqlite3_step(delete_statment);
    
    if (success != SQLITE_DONE) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to save priority with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    
    sqlite3_reset(delete_statment);
}
```

I googled for the problem and found that it might be because I am accessing database from different threads. As thecode starts I am able to Read it from database. so Do I need to close something so that I can delete objects from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not connected with SQLite Database.Check your database connection.

Comment: ,Thanks boss... I closed the connection somewhere in between, so it was impossible to delete it. Thank you very much....